# Increase limit of value when infinity is reached in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Data Structure:

```
HEIGHT Category
   51        1
   45        1
   89        2
```

Objective: Calculate Geometric Mean

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('BaseFish',delimiter=',')
df.dropna(axis = 0)
df = df[df.HEIGHT != 0]
table = pd.pivot_table(df,values = 'HEIGHT',index = 'Category',aggfunc=(np.prod,np.count_nonzero))
table.insert(2,'GMEAN',0)
table['GMEAN']=table['prod']**(1/table['count_nonzero'])
```

Problem: Categories with a large number of data point produces np.prod = infinity.  Hence the final GMEAN is also infinity.

My python knowledge is very basic and the only reason I am using it because the number of data points exceeds excels limit.

Comment: Do you want to compute the geometric mean height by category?

Comment: Yes. Geometric mean of height by Category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use a pivot table here. You can group by category and then compute the geometric mean per category.

```
from scipy.stats import gmean
df.groupby('category').height.apply(gmean)
```

Or without importing `spicy.stats`:

```
gmean = lambda group: group.prod()**(1/len(group))
df.groupby('category').height.apply(gmean)
```

Comment: Works perfectly!